# How to install Python dependency if requirement doesn't have binaries uploaded

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I am having trouble locking/installing dependencies, using both Pipenv and Pip Tools.

The problem:

One of my dependencies is NewRelic, which in its [implementation](https://github.com/edmorley/newrelic-python-agent/blob/ac97c23fd5b8e821be8da91f906850ce0499126b/newrelic/newrelic.egg-info/requires.txt) doesn't pin a specific version to Protobuf library.

When I lock the dependencies, generating a `Pipfile.lock` or even a `requirements.txt` with hashes, it pins [Protobuf](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/#history) to 3.12.1, which is, as of today, the latest version.

Happens that, for some unknown reason for me, Protobuf doesn't have a compatible version with my environment, and the install fails.

How could I either specify a version for Protobuf in my Pipfile or make the lock resolve the latest **compatible** version?

**EDIT**: There is also an unresolved [GitHub issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/7520) about the Protobuf problem.

Comment: Try to pin `protobuf` to `3.11.3` since it has sdit files uploaded on PyPI.

Comment: Works, thanks @AlbertTugushev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Albert, the solution is to explicitly add the failed library into the requirements file, pinned to a version that is compatible with the version of the first library and that does have a sdist on PyPI.

Pip is smart enough to see that the library is already present and does not fetch it again when resolving the sub-requirements, solving the problem.